# select rows having time difference less than 2 hour of a single column

Tags: sql, oracle

Table: TEST

[image: Table : TEST]

**Select rows having time difference less than 2 hour for the same day (group by date).**

Here output should be first two rows, because the Time difference  of the first two rows (18-JAN-15 01.08.40.000000000 PM - 18-JAN-15 11.21.28.000000000 AM < 2 hour)

```
NB: compare rows of same date.
```

OUTPUT:

[image: Output]

```
  CREATE TABLE TEST
  ( "ID" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "CAM_TIME" TIMESTAMP (6)
  ) 

Insert into TEST (ID,CAM_TIME) values ('1',to_timestamp('18-JAN-15 11.21.28.000000000 AM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'));
Insert into TEST (ID,CAM_TIME) values ('2',to_timestamp('18-JAN-15 01.08.40.000000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'));

Insert into TEST (ID,CAM_TIME) values ('3',to_timestamp('23-JAN-15 09.18.40.000000000 AM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'));
Insert into TEST (ID,CAM_TIME) values ('4',to_timestamp('23-JAN-15 04.22.22.000000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'));
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried.

Comment: Mind giving us some sample data on sqlfiddle.com to work with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This self-join query does the job:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5b268/2)

```
select distinct t1.id, t1.cam_time 
  from test t1 join test t2 on t1.rowid <> t2.rowid  
    and trunc(t1.cam_time) = trunc(t2.cam_time)
  where abs(t1.cam_time-t2.cam_time) <= 2/24
  order by t1.id
```

Edit:

If cam_time is time_stamp type then condition should be:

```
where t1.cam_time between t2.cam_time - interval '2' Hour 
                      and t2.cam_time + interval '2' Hour
```

Comment: I recommend using @David Faber's solution. I tested speed of both queries on table with 10k rows and his solution took about 0,02s and mine about 40s. This is what analytic functions are for.

Answer (score 6):

I took a slightly different tack and employed the `LAG()` and `LEAD()` analytic functions:

```
WITH mydata AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, timestamp '2015-01-15 11:21:28.000' AS cam_time
    FROM dual
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, timestamp '2015-01-15 13:08:40.000' AS cam_time
    FROM dual
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS id, timestamp '2015-01-23 09:18:40.000' AS cam_time
    FROM dual
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS id, timestamp '2015-01-23 16:22:22.000' AS cam_time
    FROM dual
)
SELECT id, cam_time FROM (
    SELECT id, cam_time
         , LAG(cam_time) OVER ( PARTITION BY TRUNC(cam_time) ORDER BY cam_time ) AS lag_time
         , LEAD(cam_time) OVER ( PARTITION BY TRUNC(cam_time) ORDER BY cam_time ) AS lead_time
      FROM mydata
) WHERE CAST(lead_time AS DATE) - CAST(cam_time AS DATE) < 1/12
     OR CAST(cam_time AS DATE) - CAST(lag_time AS DATE) < 1/12
```

Comment: I suspect that your solution is the fastest.

Comment: Hard to tell with such limited data. I looked at the explain plans but four rows' worth of data isn't going to tell much.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it. With 'exist' you can check if a sub-query returns any results. In this case, the sub-query returns those rows that match 2 criteria:

1. they have the same date (`trunc(CAM_TIME)` returns the date only, which are then compared).
2. they have a time difference of less that two hours. You can subtract two times to get the difference in days. Multiply that difference by 24 to get that value in hours.

The result:

```
select
  t1.*
from 
  TEST t1
where
  exists
    ( select 'x' 
      from   TEST t2 
      where  t1.id <> t2.id                                -- Not the same row
             trunc(t2.CAM_TIME) = trunc(t1.CAM_TIME)       -- Same date
             and abs(t1.CAM_TIME - t2.CAM_TIME) * 24 < 2   -- < 2 hours
```

Comment: The only caveat I would have about this solution is that it assumes `DATE` columns and not `TIMESTAMP`s (with that # of decimal places in the OP's data, I'm guessing he has `TIMESTAMP`s). And the result of `TIMESTAMP` arithmetic is an `INTERVAL` rather than a `NUMBER`.

Comment: Good point. OP didn't specify that, but judging by the decimals you may be right. It doesn't change the query much, though. You can `cast(THOSE_TIMESTAMPS as date)`. You may loose some precision, but it's only to see if the two timestamps are within two hours of each other, so will probably be acceptable.

Comment: You're also missing a condition - need to add that `t1.id <> t2.id`