# Fetch a data if the time duration between added date and current date is not greater than or equal to 2 hours

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am creating a booking management system. I got stuck in the booking cancellation part. I want to allow users to cancel their orders if their booking time and the current time duration is between 2 hours because I want to restrict the users to cancel their booking if their booking time and current time duration is greater than or equal to 2 hours.

I want to generate a query that returns all the bookings whose booking time is less than 2 hours. How can I achieve this?

This is my database structure. [image]

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29446361/select-rows-having-time-difference-less-than-2-hour-of-a-single-column

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the hour part of your date. Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402012/select-row-by-datepart)

Then using this query to get those less than 2 hours.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE tdate - 120 < EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM now())
```

Comment: there is no such thing as `datepart` in MySQL the same post says https://stackoverflow.com/a/13402434/10342514

Comment: @donic It did not fix.

Comment: @donic Thanks, but even this does not return any row. I have two data that are added at 1.00pm and 1.14 pm.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `TableName` where TIMEDIFF(NOW(),Your_date_ColumnName) < '02:00:00.000000'
```

Comment: This return all the rows that are booked today.

Comment: this will return all the rows that are booked and  whose booking time is less than 2 hours.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `TableName` where TIMEDIFF(NOW(),added_date) < '02:00:00.000000'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `booking_time` is in MySQL standard format.

Try this and the below query will use index if you have one in `booking_time` column

```
SELECT * 
FROM booking_table 
WHERE booking_time BETWEEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```

Comment: I am generating this query `SELECT  *  FROM booking WHERE added_date BETWEEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AND sender_id = "4" ORDER BY booking.id DESC` but it soes not return any row.

Comment: Does `sender_id =4` is in the 2 hours time? Just remove `AND sender_id="4" ORDER BY booking.id DESC` then check what sender_id are really present

Comment: It does not return any row even after removing sender_id. And,the sender_id is int data, that is the user id.

Comment: Then you don't have any booking who created 2 hour before?

Comment: I don't want bookings of two hours before. I want bookings that haven't crossed two hours from the current time. Suppose, if it is 2.00 pm, I want data that are booked between 12.00pm - 2.00pm.

Comment: That's what i have shared you. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`  which gives you 2.00 pm `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR` which gives 12.00 pm so on comparison it will show the data which is between those time for `added_date`. If its not showing share the table struc and sample data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197479/discussion-between-alisha-lamichhane-and-james).

Comment: @AlishaLamichhane I hope your timezone is different in your application rather than in mysql